# racket: macro expand inside match pattern

Tags: macros, racket

Is there any way to detect if a macro is expanding inside a pattern match?

Here's an example macro that I'd like to write, but it fails inside a `match-define`:

```
#lang racket/base
(require racket/match (for-syntax racket/base syntax/parse))

(struct point (x y))

(define-syntax (friendly-point stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
   [(_ arg* ...)
    #'(begin (printf "Now making a point\n") (point arg* ...))]
   [_ #'(begin (printf "Hello point\n") point)]))

(define p (friendly-point 1 2))
 ;; Prints "Now making a point"

(match-define (friendly-point x y) p)
;; ERROR
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Instead of using an ordinary syntax transformer created with `define-syntax`, use [`define-match-expander`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._define-match-expander%29%29) to create a macro that can [cooperate with](https://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/publications/jfp12-draft-fcdf.pdf) `match`.

```lisp
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-match-expander positive
  (syntax-parser
    [(_ n)
     #'(? positive? n)]))

(match 3
  [(positive n) (~a n " is positive")])
; => "3 is positive"
```

The `define-match-expander` form is flexible: it can be used to create macros that may *only* be used inside of `match`, but it can also be used to create macros that expand differently depending on how they are used by providing two transformer functions, one for each context. This allows you to have “context-sensitive” identifiers which work as both functions *and* as match expanders.

```lisp
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse)
         (prefix-in base: racket/base))

(define-match-expander syntax
  (syntax-parser
    [(_ x)
     #'(? syntax? (app syntax->datum x))])
  (make-rename-transformer #'base:syntax))

(match (syntax (1 2 3))
  [(syntax n) (~a n " is a syntax list")])
```

If you need *even more* flexibility, you can forego `define-match-expander` entirely and define a custom struct with the [`prop:match-expander`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._prop~3amatch-expander%29%29) structure type property. This can be combined with `prop:procedure` to achieve the two-argument functionality described above, but it can also hold state, and it can be paired with *other* structure type properties such as `prop:rename-transformer` to allow the same identifier to function in many, many different contexts.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is [`define-match-expander`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html?q=define-match-expander#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._define-match-expander%29%29). It allows you to make a macro that is expanded inside of a pattern matching context. (Also, because it takes in two thunks, you can have a variant that is also used when not in a matching context. Next, I should point out that

Next, you can have a printing side effect inside of the template of a `define-match-expander`, but you can have in the macro itself. (Note though that the side effect will not occur if your module has already been expanded. This is explain in more detail [in this paper](https://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/publications/macromod.pdf).

So, using match expanders, including a second function for use outside of match, you get the following code:

```
#lang racket/base

(require racket/match (for-syntax racket/base syntax/parse))

(struct point (x y))

(define-match-expander friendly-point
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-parse stx
      [(_ arg* ...)
       (printf "Now matching a point\n")
       #'(point arg* ...)]
      [_ #'point]))
  (lambda (stx)
    (syntax-parse stx
      [(_ args* ...)
       #'(begin (printf "Now making a point\n") (point args* ...))])))

(define p (friendly-point 1 2))
 ;; Prints "Now making a point"

(match-define (friendly-point x y) p)
;; Works fine now
```